# Clear clipboard on form close C#

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, formclosing

when I close my program, it will execute my last clipboard.gettext when I paste it. I want when I close the program that no longer carries out that last clipboard.gettext command.

What I've already tried is to encode this code behind my wndproc but that didn't help me any further:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, _clipboardViewerNext);        // Removes our from the chain of clipboard viewers when the form closes.
}
```

**And this is code of**

```
       [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);
        private IntPtr _ClipboardViewerNext;

        //Make some global variables so we can access them somewhere else later
        //This will store all Questions and Answers
        //In here will be the Questions and Answers
        List<question> questionList = new List<question>();
        // Demonstrates SetText, ContainsText, and GetText.



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set our application as a clipboard viewer
            _ClipboardViewerNext = SetClipboardViewer(Handle);
            this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;

            //Add question/answer to list
            //hoofdstuk 3 it
            question newQuestion = new question("wat is de hoofdstad van nederland?", "Amsterdam.*");

        }

        private void GetAnswer(string clipboardText)
        {
            //Loop through all questions and answers
            foreach (question q in questionList)
            {
                //If we have found an answer that is exactly the same show an Notification
                if (q._question == clipboardText)
                {
                    ShowNotification(q._question, q._answer);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ShowNotification(string question, string answer)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = question;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = answer;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            {
                const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
                if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
                {
                    GetAnswer(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText));
                }

            }
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'ld suggest to use the more recent, less disruption-prone [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) (paired with [RemoveClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-removeclipboardformatlistener)) to manage Clipboard notifications.

Comment: Are you creating a new account for each question you ask?  This is at least the 3rd time I have seen that `WndProc` code each by a different account in the past 2 weeks;  User #10479535 (account closed), #11238037, and this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried using `Clipboard.Clear()` method..?

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

Full C# code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsTestForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clipboard.SetText("Testing...");
            this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //Clipboard.SetText(" "); // Value cannot be null
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Resources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: The clipboard.clear (); method I have already tried. What happens then is that he is the last clipboard.gettext (); method still does.

Comment: i updated my code to my full code because your code also did'nt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 Clipboard.SetDataObject(string.Empty);
```

Complete Code

```
this.FormClosing += (s, ev) => { Clipboard.SetDataObject(string.Empty); };
```

Comment: I think i need something to clear WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD in my WndProc